# Split Multi-User MS Access Db. Table overwrite issue

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have a split multi-user Db where the backend is encrypted, not allowing for pessimistic locking. The tasks in the table in the backend is preloaded daily with the assigned field auto-populated as Unassigned. When an employee clicks begin task or submit to goto the next task, a dlookup identifies the next "Unassigned" task via dlookup and updates the field to their name.

The problem I am experiencing is the table does not seem to be updating quickly enough so I am encountering several people's front end (using accde) not recognizing that table has been updated and overwriting the same record. I have updated auto refresh to two seconds from 60, yet I am not getting the desired results.

Is there a way I can refresh the actual linked table on each command button click for the vba to see, in real time, the correct record to move to?

Below is the code for my "Begin" button. The "Submit/Next Task" button uses the same kind of coding to look for the next task.

```
Private Sub butagingicoms202_begin_Click()
Dim strsql As String
Dim AuditCheck As String
Dim NYPhone As String
Dim CAPhone As String
Dim LastTask As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  If IsNull(DLookup("[Sys]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "assigned = 'unassigned'")) Then
 LastTask = True
 Else
 LastTask = False
 End If
 If LastTask = True Then
 MsgBox "All tasks have been assigned. Please move on to your next assigned project"
 DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 DoCmd.Close acForm, "Aging_ICOMS202DailyWorkable_frm"
 Else
Call RandomTime
butagingicoms202_submit.Visible = True
Me.butagingicoms202_submit.SetFocus
butagingicoms202_queue.Visible = True
butagingicoms202_begin.Visible = False
txtagingicoms202_sysacct = DLookup("[sysacct]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "[SYS]=202 AND [Assigned] = 'unassigned' AND [SecondaryTask]<>'50 Day'  AND [SecondaryTask]<>'Spec Review' AND [SecondaryTask]<>'Low Bal Rpt'")
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Aging_ICOMSWorkable SET assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "' WHERE sysacct = [txtagingicoms202_sysacct]"
txtagingicoms202_acct = DLookup("[AccountNumber]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
txtagingicoms202_sys = DLookup("[Sys]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
txtagingicoms202_name = DLookup("[Name]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
'txtagingicoms202_fn = DLookup("[FirstName]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "[Assigned] = 'unassigned'")
'txtagingicoms202_ln = DLookup("[LastName]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "[Assigned] = 'unassigned'")
txtagingicoms202_task = DLookup("[Task]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
txtagingicoms202_tt = DLookup("[Task]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
txtagingicoms202_assignment = DLookup("[SecondaryTask]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
'NYPhone = DLookup("[NYSTATE]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & me.txtagingicoms202_assigned &"'")
'CAPhone = DLookup("[PW CAL PHONE?]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & me.txtagingicoms202_assigned &"'")
txtagingicoms202_TotalAR = "$" & Format(DLookup("[Total A/R Balance]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'"), "0.00")
txtagingicoms202_PDbal = "$" & Format(DLookup("[Delinquent Balance]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'"), "0.00")

'txtagingicoms202_secassign = DLookup("[Secondary Task]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "[Assigned] = 'unassigned'")
txtagingicoms202_starttime = Now()
strsql = "UPDATE Aging_ICOMSWorkable SET Start_Time = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_starttime & "' WHERE sysacct = [txtagingicoms202_sysacct]"
DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
Me.comagingicoms202_res.RowSource = "SELECT [ResolutionCodes] FROM [Resolutions]" & "WHERE [tasktype] = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_tt & "'"
Me.comagingicoms202_res.Requery
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, but it should do the trick.

```
Private Sub butagingicoms202_begin_Click()
  Dim strsql  As String
  Dim AuditCheck As String
  Dim NYPhone As String
  Dim CAPhone As String
  doCmd.SetWarnings False
  If IsNull(DLookup("[Sys]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "assigned = 'unassigned'")) Then
    MsgBox "All tasks have been assigned. Please move on to your next assigned project"
    doCmd.SetWarnings True
    doCmd.Close acForm, "Aging_ICOMS202DailyWorkable_frm"
  Else
    Call RandomTime
    butagingicoms202_submit.Visible = True
    Me.butagingicoms202_submit.SetFocus
    butagingicoms202_queue.Visible = True
    butagingicoms202_begin.Visible = False
'    txtagingicoms202_sysacct = DLookup("[sysacct]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "[SYS]=202 AND [Assigned] = 'unassigned' AND [SecondaryTask]<>'50 Day'  AND [SecondaryTask]<>'Spec Review' AND [SecondaryTask]<>'Low Bal Rpt'")
'    doCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Aging_ICOMSWorkable SET assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "' WHERE sysacct = [txtagingicoms202_sysacct]"
    doCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Aging_ICOMSWorkable SET assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "' WHERE sysacct = " & _
                 DLookup("[sysacct]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "[SYS]=202 AND [Assigned] = 'unassigned' AND [SecondaryTask]<>'50 Day' " & _
                                      "AND [SecondaryTask]<>'Spec Review' AND [SecondaryTask]<>'Low Bal Rpt'")
    txtagingicoms202_acct = DLookup("[AccountNumber]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
    txtagingicoms202_sys = DLookup("[Sys]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
    txtagingicoms202_name = DLookup("[Name]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
    txtagingicoms202_task = DLookup("[Task]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
    txtagingicoms202_tt = DLookup("[Task]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
    txtagingicoms202_assignment = DLookup("[SecondaryTask]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'")
    txtagingicoms202_TotalAR = "$" & Format(DLookup("[Total A/R Balance]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'"), "0.00")
    txtagingicoms202_PDbal = "$" & Format(DLookup("[Delinquent Balance]", "Aging_ICOMSWorkable", "sysacct = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_sysacct & "' AND assigned = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_assigned & "'"), "0.00")

    txtagingicoms202_starttime = Now()
    strsql = "UPDATE Aging_ICOMSWorkable SET Start_Time = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_starttime & "' WHERE sysacct = [txtagingicoms202_sysacct]"
    doCmd.RunSQL strsql
    Me.comagingicoms202_res.RowSource = "SELECT [ResolutionCodes] FROM [Resolutions]" & "WHERE [tasktype] = '" & Me.txtagingicoms202_tt & "'"
    Me.comagingicoms202_res.Requery
    doCmd.SetWarnings True
  End If
End Sub
```

I made 3 changes:

- I remove the lines you had commented. If you really need them, put them back in
- I removed the `LastTask` variable and the `If` statement that set it. I incorporated it into one `If` statement that check for your `IsNull` condition and pops up a warning message if you're at the end of the work queue or falls into the assignment logic if not. This will reduce some of the lag that could induce a race condition when 2 people attempt to grab the very last task.
- You were using 2 statements to A) identify the next available task, then B) assign it to the current user. I've combined these into one statement so it identifies and assigns in one atomic `UPDATE` statement. I believe that this will lock the record you're attempting to update at the moment you're updating it to prevent anyone else from doing so.

  - This is the untested part. You may need to debug your code then see exactly what what is being passed to `.RunSQL` to ensure that it's valid code. If not, tweak a little until you get something Access can parse.
  - You'll want to wrap some error handling around this, just in case you and I end up in a race for this record, only one of us can win - you'll want your error handling to retry this statement for the looser - he can just execute it again to get the next task up for grabs.
  - Now that I think about it, you may want to put the `LastTask` code in the error handling so that you don't put someone in an infinite loop if there are no more tasks to be handled. Your `LastTask` might execute more quickly if you test `If SELECT COUNT(*)... > 0` instead of using a `DLookup()`. I don't have documentation to hand, but I recall that the `DLookup()` function is known for being rather slow.

A couple of additional code clean up suggestions:

- `Call` is an obsolete term and is only included for backward compatibility. Your `Call RandomTime` will work just fine if you change it to `RandomTime`.
- You have descriptive names for your form controls, which is excellent, but the lack of "punctuation" or capitalization make them very hard to read. You may consider for example changing `butagingicoms202` to `butAgingIcoms202` (my recommendation) or `but_aging_icoms_202` because that's easier for people to parse.

Comment: Thanks FreeMan -- I'll work on these updates and come back w/ results. I really appreciate the detail here.

Comment: Happy to help! If you find this helpful, don't forget to click the up arrow, and if you feel that this has provided your answer, click the check mark when you're ready.

Comment: While I am working on this, another thought popped into my mind. I am able to set record locking through the FE before converting to accde. Is there also a way to keep a record 'locked' after initial update and then 'release' after submitting the task? I'm thinking with the revised code and added error handling, this might be a final step to expunge the overwriting issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, however, this is very similar to what I wrote at a previous company to alleviate the same situation. YMMV.